# How to check file name for non-ASCII characters via JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, uploadify

I am using jQuery Uploadify to upload a file directly to S3. Everything works so far.

What I need now is to validate the file via JS. To make sure that all characters are ASCII compatible.

How can this be done?

Comment: If you want to make something sure, **DO NOT** validate it with JS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printable ASCII characters start at `0x20` (space) to `0x7E` (~). The RegExp to match this range is: `[\x20-\x7E]`.

So, the final code:

```
var filename = "foo.bar";
if(/^[\x20-\x7E]+$/.test(filename)){
    //Valid, continue
} else {
    //Invalid, notify the user
}
```